# what's the stack space of this code?

Tags: binary-search-tree

The question is to check if a Tree is a valid BST. There are two recursive method to solve. I think their space complexity both are O(logN), N is the number of TreeNode, so logN is actually the height of tree. But in a solution book, it said the stack space is O(N), I can't figure out. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

```
public class Solution {
        public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
            return isValidBST(root, null, null);
        }

        private boolean isValidBST(TreeNode x, Integer min, Integer max) {
            return x == null || (min == null || x.val > min) && (max == null || x.val < max) &&
                                isValidBST(x.left, min, x.val) && isValidBST(x.right, x.val, max);
        }
    }

public class Solution {
    private TreeNode prev;

    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
        prev = null;
        return isMonotonicIncreasing(root);
    }

    private boolean isMonotonicIncreasing(TreeNode p) {
        if (p == null)  return true;
        if (isMonotonicIncreasing(p.left)) {
            if (prev != null && p.val <= prev.val) return false;
            prev = p;
            return isMonotonicIncreasing(p.right);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the problem Maximum Depth of Binary Tree(https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/), the book said the space is O(logN), return (root == null) ? 0 : 1 + Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right));  I think they are the same.

Comment: It's `O(N)` because an unbalanced tree can be as deep as `O(N)` if it degrades to a linked list.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense. But for the problem Maximum Depth of Binary Tree in the Leetcode which I have mentioned above. The official solution said the space cost is O(logN), the binary tree can also be unbalanced. So I still feel confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Space requirements will be O(h), where h is the height of the tree.

Log(n) is the best case for this code when the tree is balanced.

But in case of skewed trees the space complexity will be O(n) i.e. linear.

For example, for following trees, the code will take Exactly S(n) space:

```
               1                            5    
                 2                        4
                   3                    3
                     4                2 
                       5            1
```